# Does this martingale representation hold?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Consider an SDE:

$$dX_t = \mu(t,X_t)dt + \sigma(t,X_t)dW_t,   \hspace{1cm} t \in [0:T]$$

where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are Lipschitz continuous in $t$ and $x$. Define some Lipschitz continuous function $g$.

(Lets assume that $X_t$ is Markov process). By the Markov property of $X$: $\mathbb{E}(g(X_T)|\mathcal{F}_t) = f(t,X_t)$ for some measurable function $f(t,x)$

If $f$ was differentiable in $t$ and twice differentiable  in $x$ by Ito's formula then:

$$f(T,X_{T}) = f(t,X_t) + \int_t^{T} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \mu(s,X_s)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(s,X_s)\right) ds + \int_t^{T}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\sigma(s,X_s)dW_s$$

$$g(X_{T}) = f(t,X_t) + \int_t^{T}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \mu(s,X_s)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(s,X_s)\right) ds + \int_t^{T}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\sigma(s,X_s)dW_s$$

But the process $f(t,X_t)$ is a martingale and thus

$$g(X_T) - f(t,X_t) = \int_t^{T}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\sigma(s,X_s)dW_s$$

My question is, suppose now that we don't have it as given that $f$ is differentiable in $x$  and differentiable in $t$, can we deduce that

$$g(X_T) - f(t,X_t) = \int_t^{T}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(s,X_s)\sigma(s,X_s)dW_s$$ ?

Motivation:

Intuitively conditional expectation should smoothen function $g$ knowing that $\mu, \sigma, g$ are Lipschitz continuous, and maybe it is possible to prove that function $f(t,x)$ is differentiable.

From martingale representation theorem  there must be some adapted process $Z_s$ such that

$$g(X_T) - f(t,X_t) = \int_t^{T}Z_sdW_s$$

And if $f(t,x)$ is differentiable in $x$ intuitively it must be

$Z_s = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(s,X_s)\sigma(s,X_s) $

Comment: Why should $\mathbb{E}(g(X_{T})|X_{t+1}) - \mathbb{E}(g(X_{T})|X_t)$ be a martingale?

Comment: @NateEldredge   I made a slight mistake $S_t = \mathbb{E}(g(X_T)|X_t)$ is a martingale process

Comment: @NateEldredge I edited the question

Comment: I still don't see how you know that $\mathbb{E}(g(X_T)|X_t)$ is a martingale.  It's true that a process of the form $\mathbb{E}[g(X_T) \mid \mathcal{F}_t]$ would be a martingale, but that is not what we have, and $\sigma(X_t)$ is in general not a filtration.

Comment: @NateEldredge I edited the question, is it okay now?

Comment: Just a question (I guess Nate Eldredge can help more than me... ) . Why in the initial stochastic equation $\mu$ and $\sigma$ do not depend on $t$ and they have only one argument, but than a further dependence is introduced in the integral solution ?

Comment: @Thomas I just wanted to ensure that process $X$ is Markov, and it is if coefficients are time homogenous. I think I will rewrite the question

Comment: Just for clarification and not to answer your question, are you sure that the process defined by that SDE is not always Markov, even if the coefficients are not time homogeneous ? Here it seems to be written that the Markov property is always respected https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation . After all, otherwise you could not use the Euler-Murayama scheme to integrate it I guess.

Comment: @Thomas I always thought so too, but when I started reading some references like Protter's book , there they proved it only for time homogoenous coefficients, and I started to doubt a little

Comment: Well, I hope somebody more expert of the field can comment more on your question.